# Why don't these totals match

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate tax and a discount. Here is the formula I'm using but the query returns short.

```
((8.75+0)/100)*(50.00*1 - (50*1*.1/100)) as test,
```

MySQL retuens 4.370625 and when I do the math (0.0875 * 50 - 0.05) on a calculator, I get: 3.875

Where am I going wrong?

---

**Lets take this real world example**

```
A single item for sale:
Quantity:  1.00
Price: $20.00
Tax: 8.75%
Discount: 10%

The tax should equal: $1.58
The subtotal without tax is $18.00
Total: $19.58 (after the discount and tax added)
```

How do I write the query to get the tax **and a separate calculation** to get the discount?

Answer (score 4):

You should do `0.0875 * (50 - 0.05)`. First difference, then multiplication.

```
((8.75+0)/100)*(50.00*1 - (50*1*.1/100))

( 8.75   /100)*(50      -  0.05        )

  0.0875      *(50      -  0.05        )

  0.0875      * 49.95

  4.370625
```

Your real life example (if all numbers are like here):

```
A single item for sale:
Quantity:  1.00
Price: $20.00
Tax: 8.75%
Discount: 10%


"Total Tax" = Quantity * (Price * (1. - (Discount / 100.)) * (Tax / 100.)
"Subtotal without tax" = Quantity * (Price * (1. - (Discount / 100.))
"Total" = Quantity * (Price * (1. - Discount / 100.) * (1. + Tax / 100.))
```

Comment: eumiro, I totally suck at figuring out the formula for this and quite honestly, I've been at this way too long. Can you please help me put together to columns that calculate a tax and a discount?

Comment: @Jim - I have just taken your formula from MySQL and tried to simplify it step by step.

Comment: Thanks eumiro. I've posted a real-world example of what I'm trying to write in SQL in my post above.

Answer (score 2):

it's 4.370625. You're doing your math wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your formula calculates (0.0875*(50-0.05))

3.875 is 0.0875*50-0.5 (wrong parentheses and 0.5 instead of 0.05)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the math wrong, it's not (0.0875 * 50 - 0.05) but (0.0875 * (50 - 0.05)) = 4.370625

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the operator precedence right? This is what happens:

```
((8.75+0)/100)*(50.00*1 - (50*1*.1/100))
```

which evaluates as

```
((8.75+0)/100)*((50.00*1) - (50*1*.1/100))
```

which is somewhat suspect (why are you multiplying by one?) Did you mean this?

```
((8.75+0)/100)*(50.00*(1 - (50*1*.1/100)))
```

Comment: Piskvor, I have absolutely no idea. I can't even think at this point.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate tax and a discount per item is all. I can do this without a hitch on a calculator but writing the SQL has proven to be more than a headache and nightmare to say the least. Nothing adds up

Comment: I multiplied by one just to test the query.